# MySQL return result by quantity per row

Tags: mysql

I need a query that requires me to return something like below.

```
data table
--------------------------------
product name | quantity
apple        | 3
egg          | 2

query expected result
--------------------------------
product name
apple
apple
apple
egg
egg
```

Thanks for feedback

UPDATE #1
ok my bad the question is unclear. I want to display my result by looping my product by quantity. Probably my expected result on quantity makes some confusion. Therefore, is that possible to loop my record by quantity in mysql?

Comment: Why don't you try something first and let us know of any issues

Comment: need more information. what are you using to query?

Comment: Query for the product's quantity and loop that many times... ?

Comment: i tried with simple SELECT query. but i don't know how to loop by quantity. @d_ominic

Comment: yes exactly what you said. @JoeDF

Comment: Which programming language are you using with that? You could have MySQL just return the counts and use your programming language to run loops on that count

Comment: Even if it is possible, I'd strongly recommend you to not use MySQL for display purposes. The purpose of it is selecting data, not displaying it. Use your front end framework (php?) for that instead.

Comment: hi @sashkello please find the updated question

Comment: oh okay... i was wondering if sql possible to do this... anyway, thanks guys n sorry for the confusion.

Comment: it's possible in SQL, but it is NOT easy to have a non-trivial query turn ONE row of data into MULTIPLE rows the way you want. You have a display problem, not a query problem. display problems are client-side problems at that.

Comment: ok thanks for reply @MarcB then i don't see it's a good idea to make things difficult...

Comment: this is actually not all that difficult to do, depending on what all you have in your table but it is not recommended as everyone is saying... it would be much better to do in a programming language after pulling out the data.
what you could do though is a select of your count and then a select as a select i.e SELECT ProductName, Count, (select ProductName... then have a where conditional that would make it repeat. I did this off of a date created column but then just did it in python for runtime sake.

Comment: i agreed that. @JohnRuddell i just query twice for total quantity and all records from the table and display with php which is my programming language right now.

Comment: if you dont want to go the route of creating a new table then all you have to do is pull it out like the first results you show with 3 counts of apple and 2 counts of egg. for loop in php where you build a list of the food names going off of the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need this in SQL you can leverage a tally(numbers) table, which you can create and populate with values 1-100 like so

```
CREATE TABLE tally(n INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO tally (n)
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
 FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
ORDER BY n;
```

Then your query would look

```
SELECT product_name
  FROM data_table d JOIN tally t
    ON t.n <= d.quantity
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have `MAX(n)` value in your `tally` table >= `MAX(quantity)` in your `data_table` for this to work properly

Output:

```
+--------------+
| product_name |
+--------------+
| apple        |
| apple        |
| apple        |
| egg          |
| egg          |
+--------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04117/1)** demo

Comment: wow brilliant. i need time to digest this statement. thanks man @peterm